# Enforce strong password policy with parsley.js

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I have a password field that i will like to ensure that the users input a password that will meet the criteria stated below:-

1. Must contain at least one capital letter
2. Must contain at least one small letter
3. Must contain a number and lastly
4. A special character like #%@!*(()+= ( optional )

I have tried to use the data-parsley-pattern, and data-parsley-type but not getting the required results.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.6.0/parsley.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate>                             
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="6" data-parsley-type="alphanum" data-parsley-pattern="^/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]$/" class="form-control allForms" required data-parsley-required-message="Your password" data-parsley-trigger="change focusin" placeholder="Enter password">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that for efficiency and maintainability you should either define a custom validator like explained [here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#custom) or a regex one if you're good at it (`((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?(?=.*[#%@!*(()+=]))).{6,16}` could do the job?);)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.6.0/parsley.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate>                             
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="6" data-parsley-type="alphanum" data-parsley-pattern="^/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]$/" class="form-control allForms" required data-parsley-required-message="Your password" data-parsley-trigger="change focusin" placeholder="Enter password">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi HMT, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I suggest that you provide some context and explanation of your answer. This will make it easier to understand, and more likely to help the OP and others who come to this question for help.