# Parsley custom validator - password with number, uppercase letter and special character

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley

I'm using Parsley to validate a registration form. The client has now asked to force users to use at least one uppercase letter, number and special character. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this by creating a custom validator with Parsley, rather than implementing additional code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforce strong password policy with parsley.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453419/enforce-strong-password-policy-with-parsley-js)

Answer (score 2):

```
data-parsley-pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data-parsley-pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\pL\s\-]+$"
```

include your special character as"\special_character" inside square bracket